# How to parse a stacked nested JSON file in R?

Tags: r, json, parsing, stacked

I am trying to use R to parse a file of stacked JSON messages that look like so:

```
{"ts":1.592932195038E9,"accel1":[{"x":26125,"y":-29824,"z":-254468,"id":"3"},{"x":27508,"y":242227,"z":84591,"id":"4"},{"x":-250265,"y":41250,"z":-11000,"id":"5"},{"x":-16089,"y":-256369,"z":17448,"id":"7"}]}
{"ts":1.592932195058E9,"accel1":[{"x":26107,"y":-29807,"z":-254479,"id":"3"},{"x":27508,"y":242227,"z":84591,"id":"4"},{"x":-250265,"y":41250,"z":-11000,"id":"5"},{"x":-16089,"y":-256369,"z":17448,"id":"7"}]}
{"ts":1.592932195078E9,"accel1":[{"x":26107,"y":-29807,"z":-254479,"id":"3"},{"x":27490,"y":242252,"z":84604,"id":"4"},{"x":-250301,"y":41180,"z":-10922,"id":"5"},{"x":-16122,"y":-256392,"z":17390,"id":"7"}]}
...
```

Because the messages are stacked, I was unable to use fromJSON and instead used jsonlite::stream_in to read each JSON message into a data frame like so:

```
flatten(jsonlite::stream_in(file("Data.json")))
```

The output of which is:

```
            ts                                                                                                   accel1
1   1592932195 26125, 27508, -250265, -16089, -29824, 242227, 41250, -256369, -254468, 84591, -11000, 17448, 3, 4, 5, 7
2   1592932195 26107, 27508, -250265, -16089, -29807, 242227, 41250, -256369, -254479, 84591, -11000, 17448, 3, 4, 5, 7
3   1592932195 26107, 27490, -250301, -16122, -29807, 242252, 41180, -256392, -254479, 84604, -10922, 17390, 3, 4, 5, 7
...
```

R is now treating all of the columns within "accel1" as one big column and is either hiding or throwing out "x", "y", "z", and "id". On top of that the data is now read in a different order (`x,x,x,x,y,y,y,y,z,z,z,z,id,id,id,id` instead of the desired `x,y,z,id,x,y,z,id...`) How can I read the file so that each column within "accel1" is treated separately with its own column name and possibly in the desired order?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to address this is likely with `tidyr::unnest`:

```r
### highlight the above and run this
js <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(paste(readLines("clipboard"), collapse = "\n")))
#  Imported 3 records. Simplifying...
unnest(js, accel1)
# # A tibble: 12 x 5
#             ts       x       y       z id   
#          <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>
#  1 1592932195.   26125  -29824 -254468 3    
#  2 1592932195.   27508  242227   84591 4    
#  3 1592932195. -250265   41250  -11000 5    
#  4 1592932195.  -16089 -256369   17448 7    
#  5 1592932195.   26107  -29807 -254479 3    
#  6 1592932195.   27508  242227   84591 4    
#  7 1592932195. -250265   41250  -11000 5    
#  8 1592932195.  -16089 -256369   17448 7    
#  9 1592932195.   26107  -29807 -254479 3    
# 10 1592932195.   27490  242252   84604 4    
# 11 1592932195. -250301   41180  -10922 5    
# 12 1592932195.  -16122 -256392   17390 7
```

Comment: HH, does this help you at all? If so, please accept it. Thank you!